# How to pass Js variable through html anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel-5, anchor

Here I am trying to pass the id to the controller like this `{{ route("admin.service.edit", '+val[0]+' )}}`

but the `'+val[0]+'` is consider as a string in url `http://localhost:8000/admin/service/**+val%5B0%5D+**/edit`

but the variable looks like +val%5B0%5D+ in URL but I want its value

this is my anchor tag

```
<a href="{{ route("admin.service.edit",'+val[0]+')}}"></a>
```

Below is the full code

```
$.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/admin/service/show_list',
       data:{ modality_id: m, center_id: h },
       success:function(data) {
           $("#service-table > tbody").empty();
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each( data.service_list1, function( i, val ) {
                    trHTML +='<tbody><tr id="myTableRow" style="text-align:center;"><td>' + val[0] + '</td><td>' + val[1] + '</td><td><a href="{{ route("admin.service.edit",'+val[0]+')}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit Service"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td></tr></tbody>';
                });
                $('#service-table').append(trHTML);
                }
       });
```

But I want to pass the value of that variable in URL so how I am able to do it ??

Advance Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. What is "the bold part"? Please revise to explain better what you're trying to do and what you need (how it's not working). It would help if you'd remove non-essential stuff like all those Bootstrap classes, icon elements, and inline styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution

I am saved the route and id in a variable then replace :id value by ***url.replace*** function.

Below is the Code

```
var url = '{{ route("admin.service.edit", ":id") }}';
url = url.replace(':id', val[0]);
<a href="'+url+'" title="Edit Service"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing [server-side code and client-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/328193).  This entire expression is evaluated server-side:

```
{{ route("admin.service.edit",'+val[0]+')}}
```

Which, so the server, just uses the literal string value `'+val[0]+'`.  JavaScript isn't involved on the server.  *After* the result of this is put in the page, the resulting page is delivered to the browser.  (As an exercise, take a look at your browser's View Source option and see exactly what's in that JavaScript code.)

A possible workaround for this is, instead of trying to put the JavaScript value into the server-side operation directly, use a placeholder value and then replace that value client-side.  For example, perhaps something like this:

```
{{ route("admin.service.edit","REPLACEME")}}
```

Then in your JavaScript code you would have this:

```
trHTML +=
  '[removed for brevity]<a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/service/REPLACEME/edit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit Service"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td></tr></tbody>';
```

And you can use JavaScript to replace that known placeholder with the intended client-side value:

```
trHTML +=
  '[removed for brevity]<a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/service/REPLACEME/edit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit Service"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td></tr></tbody>'
  .replace('REPLACEME', val[0]);
```